# Increment number with prepending 0 in php

Tags: php

When I am trying to increment number 032, its removing first 0 and showing output as 33.

Following is my code:

```
echo $oldStep = substr($model->business_process_id, 6, 3)+1;
```

Here $model->business_process_id become 032 after `substr` from string and when I am trying to increment it plus 1 then its removing 0 and giving output as `33` instead of `033`.

My requirement is to increment number by 1.

Ex.

```
001 after increment +1 should be 002
012 after increment +1 should be 013
112 after increment +1 should be 113
```

I tried `str_pad` and `sprint_f` but its not working for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to increment it and then use the str_pad to add a 0. You say you tried it. This should work.

Comment: How did you tried to use `str_pad()` ?

Comment: Try: `str_pad($oldStep, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: `echo str_pad($substr($model->business_process_id, 6, 3)+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);` I tried like this

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/C9mP5)

Comment: Instead of 2 you should put the length to 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, using `sprintf()`:

```
$oldStep = substr($model->business_process_id, 6, 3)+1; // 33
$oldStepPadded = sprintf("%03d", $oldStep); // 033
```

Comment: It worked...Thankssss.. I dont know but I was wrong somewhere.. anyway thanks

Comment: I came here to make the very same suggestion, but you got here first and answered it in style. I love `sprintf` :)